# Notification click but not need start newly activity?

Tags: eclipse, android-intent, android-notifications

I am new in android development. I have apps where I play one audio. When I run my apps then play that audio. I want audio playing when go another apps(back button/home). I have also one notification bar. When I click that notification bar. Then will run that activity which is playing audio. But not starting that audio again (remain before audio playing). It is possible.

My code is below:

```
Notification.Builder mBuilder =
            new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.cmplayer)
            .setContentTitle("CoderoMusicPlayer")
            .setContentText("PLayer0!");

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, 

    AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.class);
        resultIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        resultIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                resultIntent, 0);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

[Full Code]

http://pastebin.com/Xw5U0bqH

Finally, I want to run at a time audio run one times all time. Either I keep on the apps or out of the apps.

any suggestion or idea or solution for solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code where you started to play your audio and other relevant methods?

Comment: i write code inside of onCreate() methods. @ljpv14

Answer (score 0):

You need set flag for intent before start.

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.class);
        resultIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        resultIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Hope it helpful with you.